# Integrating Emacs org-mode with email?

Tags: emacs, org-mode

Has anyone does this successfully? I searched a lot but didn't find anything which worked. Before spending time myself, I just want to ask if someone has done this and would be willing to share it. :)
For example, I would like to email the agenda to myself daily, reminders when a task is nearing deadline, etc.

Comment: it seems like it would be easier to write some kind of script to export your agenda, set that script to a cron tab, then push it to your cal server, or gCal, then subscribe to that calendar with your mail client.

Comment: What are you using for your email client/where are you hoping to see your calendar? Org-Agenda would provide you most of that information within Emacs.

Answer (score 10):

If you're looking for a separate non-emacs application that will integrate well with emacs in org-mode, I would say no, you're probably not not going to find anything.  If you really like the emacs way of doing things, I would suggest trying out Gnus for your email.  If you've ever used any of the old terminal based emails, it's a pretty similar interface.  It has POP and IMAP support, so you can get your email from exchange servers and gmail.

If you're using capture in org-mode (see http://orgmode.org/manual/Using-capture.html#Using-capture), you can easily add a Todo item (or really anything) with a link back to the email, and switching between your email and agenda views becomes seamless.

For IMAP support, see https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/gnus/Using-IMAP.html 
For Gmail support, see http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/GnusGmail